# Applying jQuery mask does not support 0 as default in placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im try mask my phone input. Phone number format must be +380 (XX) XXX XX XX

But this code does it wrong. This code does +38X (XX) XXX XX XX, so zero after eight not default.

Code:

```
HTML: <div class="phone_wrap">
    Phone number: <input id="phone" data-mask="+380 (99) 999 99 99" placeholder="+380 (99) 999-99-99" type="tel" class="order_phone" >
</div>


JS(jQuery): $("#phone").mask('+380 (99) 999 99 99', {placeholder: "+380 (__) ___ __ __"});
```

Help me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.jMaskGlobals.translation["9"] = $.jMaskGlobals.translation["0"]; // reset 0 on 9
  delete $.jMaskGlobals.translation["0"]; // delete 0 as key

  $("#ph").mask('+380 (99) 999 99 99') // mask
});
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation